# Script/Automator to import large amount on images to apple photos in smaller patches

Tags: applescript, icloud, photo, automator

so I got the task to import about 4 TB of images and videos to the icloud.

When i just try to import all of them at once Photos app crashes after a few thousand images and i have to restart.

Rn the images are stored in folders and subfolders, but i can move them all into the main folder without a problem (no need for the subfolders)

Is there an apple script or Automator method to like take 5000 images, import them, take the next 5000, import them and so on (preferably with something like a progress print out „Batch 105/8772 imported“)

As explained i tried just importing all at once and the system doesnt seem stable enough